# CircleCI実行時、’command not found'　yarnがインストールできません。

Tags: docker, circleci

#### 環境

ruby 2.6.5
rails 6
MySQL
M1チップ搭載macOS

#### 解決したいこと

CircleCI起動時、’command not found'のエラーでtestが最後まで実行されません。　
yarnがインストールできません。
どういった解決策がありますか？
教えていただきたいです！

#### 発生している問題・エラー

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、”run: yarn install”の記述を取り除いてしまうと下記のエラーができます。

```
Failure/Error: <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application'%>

       ActionView::Template::Error:
         Webpacker can't find application in /home/circleci/sample_app/public/packs-test/manifest.json. Possible causes:
         1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
            unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
         2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
         3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
         4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
         Your manifest contains:
         {
         }
```

#### 該当するソースコード

**config.yml**

```yaml
version: 2.1
orbs:
  ruby: circleci/ruby@1.1.2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.5
    working_directory: ~/fridge_app
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/fridge_app
      - ruby/install-deps

  test:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.5
        - image: circleci/mysql:5.5
          environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: fridge_app_test
      environment:
        BUNDLE_JOBS: "3"
        BUNDLE_RETRY: "3"
        FRIDGE_APP_DATABASE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
        RAILS_ENV: test
      working_directory: ~/fridge_app
      steps:
        - checkout:
            path: ~/fridge_app
        - ruby/install-deps
        - run:
            name: Database setup
            command: bundle exec rails db:migrate
        - run: yarn install
        - run:
            name: test
            command: bundle exec rspec

workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/docker-image-tags.json

に、 circleci が用意する docker イメージの一覧がありますが、 ruby 系で `yarn` ないし nodejs 系のコマンドを利用したい場合には、 `-node` がついているイメージを利用する必要があります。

なので、`circleci/ruby:2.6.5` を `circleci/ruby:2.6.5-node` に変更すると、この問題は解消すると思います。

Comment: 親切にご回答ありがとうございます。
なるほど、勉強になります。無事テストの自動化できました。
本当に助かりました。